# How to integrate a flutter module in android?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dependencies, flutter-plugin

I am trying to integrate a flutter module in my android native project with Kotlin language.
I am getting errors while following the steps given in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup).

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps mentioned in the docs:

### STEP 1:

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DataStore> flutter create -t module --org com.example my_flutter

### STEP 2:

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DataStore> cd my_flutter

### STEP 3:

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DataStore\my_flutter> flutter build aar

### STEP 4:

Consuming the Module

1. OLD WAY:  Open \app\build.gradle

   NEW WAY: Add repository inside repositories block of dependencyResolutionManagement and
   pluginManagement blocks in settings.gradle
2. Ensure you have the repositories configured, otherwise add them:

> ```
>       String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
>      
>  repositories {
>         maven {
>             url 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DataStore\my_flutter\build\host\outputs\repo'
>         }
>         maven {
>             url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
>         }
>       }
> ```

3. Make the host app depend on the Flutter module:

```
dependencies {
  debugImplementation 'com.example.my_flutter:flutter_debug:1.0'
  profileImplementation 'com.example.my_flutter:flutter_profile:1.0'
  releaseImplementation 'com.example.my_flutter:flutter_release:1.0'

}
```

4. Add the `profile` build type:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    profile {
      initWith debug
    }
  }
}
```